# I cannot retrieve the username from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently trying to return the username from the firebase database in react native.  The console.log works inside the function but doesn't log anything outside of the function. I don't know where I am going wrong. Here is my code.

```
  componentWillMount() {
    firebase.database().ref('/users/' + this.userId + '/username').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    this.username = snapshot.val();
    console.log(this.username)
    });
    console.log(this.username)
    this.setState({
      username: this.username
    })
  }
```

Comment: This is expected behavior: the code *inside* the callback runs (potentially much) later than the code after it. See my explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419303/firebase-use-query-result-outside-function/35419533#35419533

Answer (score 0):

This is because of asynchronous nature of JavaScript. You should do `setState` inside the callback.

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/' + this.userId + '/username').once('value').then(snapshot => {
    this.username = snapshot.val();
    console.log(this.username);
    this.setState({
      username: this.username
    })
});
```

Comment: Possible unhandled Promise Rejection

Comment: As you have already figured out, use arrow function for callback. It will automatically bind `this` inside the callback. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, changing the syntax to es6's arrow function made the code work along with adding this.setState inside the function

```
componentWillMount() {
    firebase.database().ref('/users/' + this.userId + '/username').once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    this.username = snapshot.val();
    console.log(this.username)
    this.setState({
      username: this.username
    })
  })
  }
```