# Firebase - retrieve data using wildcards and equalto()

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using the firebase functions on the firebase database to try and pull data but I am not being successful.

The data I want to search is structured like this:

[image]

The logic of what I want to do is the following:  when a record is written to the 'jobs' collection, I want to then search the 'status' collection for availableStatus (stored as true/false).

For records that are true, I need to get the push IDs ('__zone_symbol__value') which are stored in the same 'status' collection.

In the path to the data I am after, there are two items that I will not know and need to use a wildcard, {time} and {uId}.

Here is my code I am using:

```
exports.notifyPeople = functions.database.ref('/jobs/{uId}/status')
    .onWrite(event => {
      var dbRead = admin.database().ref('status/worker/{time}/{uId}/pushToken').orderByChild('availableStatus').equalTo('true').on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
          console.log(snapshot.val());
        });

          const getPushTokens = dbRead.child;
      }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `functions.database.ref('/jobs/{uId}/status')` can be used in Cloud Functions to determine what paths the function will trigger on, it cannot be used as a wildcard when reading from the database here: `admin.database().ref('status/worker/{time}/{uId}/pushToken')`.

You will have to either know the `time` and `uId` that you want to read and use them like this:

```
let time = ...;
let uId = ...;
admin.database().ref(`status/worker/${time}/${uId}/pushToken`)
```

Or you will have to read all information for from all workers:

```
admin.database().ref("status/worker");
```

If that means that you're reading way too much data, consider adding additional data to your JSON to allow this look up to be more efficient. For example, if you keep a list of tokens for nodes that have `availableStatus` set to `true`, the lookup can be quite simple. For another example of this, see my answer here: [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)

Comment: That was what I needed.  A couple of follow up questions.  I am now using this code:       var dbRead = admin.database().ref('status/driver/').on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
      });
how do I get the results of snapshot.val so I can use them?  I can't seem to access it outside of that function.  Second, once I can read use that var, how should I read it with the variables in the path?

Comment: That first problems sounds like the very tradition async 101 problem: Firebase loads data asynchronously, so you'll have to use it in the scope where it becomes available. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419303/firebase-use-query-result-outside-function